# How to get store name bound to ComboBox in ExtJS 4.1

Tags: extjs

I have a ComboBox and store bound to it:

```
{
    name: 'month',
    store: 'Months',
    displayField: 'month_name',
    valueField: 'month_id',
    value: '01',
},
```

How to get store name? I need to get `Months` string.

I tried to use `combobox.getStore().getName()` but this method is static and I get `Object [object Object] has no method 'getName'` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the store's [`storeId`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-cfg-storeId) property.  So:

```
combobox.getStore().storeId
```